# How to hide this follow button

Tags: laravel

I built a project like instagram using laravel and vue.js.   it has models like : profile, post, user.  I just want to hide the follow button when a user wants to follow itself. In real instagram app we can't follow ourselves because there isn't any follow button in our own profile.
I made a condition that if the profile's userId equals to userId, the button hides but it doesn't work. Any opinion? Please help

This is the code that i have tried:

```php
$profileId=auth()->user()->$profile->user_id; 
$userId= $user->id;
```

In the view :

```
@if($userId == $profileId) 
    <follow-button my-user-id="{{ $user->id }}" my-profile-id="{{$profileId}}" follows="{{ $follows }}"></follow-button> 
@endif
```

Comment: can you post the code youl have tried?

Comment: @MateusJunges  Controller :
$profileId=auth()->user()->$profile->user_id;
    $userId= $user->id;
In the view :
if($userId == $profileId)
        <follow-button my-user-id="{{ $user->id }}" my-profile-id="{{$profileId}}" follows="{{ $follows }}"></follow-button>
       endif

Comment: Please edit your original post and format your code properly. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Just use Auth::user()->id; to get your logged user, and compare it with actual profile userid

Comment: @MateusJunges I approved your edit, but in the future please make it clear that the OP provided the additional information in comment so that we can approve your edit faster.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks, and sorry about that :)

Comment: It's true that i should use v-if.  But the problem is i don't know how to fetch the profile id because it returna null for that

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provide, i think that `follow button` is a vue component.
If so, just use `v-if=""` or `v-show=""` to conditionally display the button.

From the docs:

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event listeners and child components inside the conditional block are properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.
>
> v-if is also lazy: if the condition is false on initial render, it will not do anything - the conditional block won’t be rendered until the condition becomes true for the first time.
>
> In comparison, v-show is much simpler - the element is always rendered regardless of initial condition, with CSS-based toggling.
>
> Generally speaking, v-if has higher toggle costs while v-show has higher initial render costs. So prefer v-show if you need to toggle something very often, and prefer v-if if the condition is unlikely to change at runtime.

You probably should do something like this:

```php
//In your view where you want to display the follow button component:
<follow-button
    my-profile-id="{{ $profileId }}"
    my-user-id="{{ $user->id }}"
    follows="{{ $follows }}"
    v-if="{{ $profileId !== $user->id }}"
>
</follow-button>
```

Here you can [read more](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) about conditional rendering.